# Legacy vbscript to c# equivilent

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, hash, vbscript

I have inherited an old Hashing algorithm in a classic asp site that I am converting to asp.net (2.0 at this stage).

For the life of me I cannot get my head around the older function enough to be able to write the matching code in C#. I am sure it is really simple but I cannot see the woods for the trees at the moment.

Here is the original classic asp code that takes a string, any help on the equivilent C# code would be most appreciated:

```
Function PHash( pValue )
           Dim dValue 
           Dim dAccumulator
           Dim lTemp 
           Dim sValue
           sValue = UCase(Trim("" & pValue))
           dAccumulator = 0
           For lTemp = 1 to Len(sValue)
              dValue = Asc(Mid(sValue, lTemp, 1))
              If (lTemp AND 1) = 1 Then
                 dAccumulator = Sin( dAccumulator  + dValue )
              Else
                 dAccumulator = Cos( dAccumulator  + dValue )
              End If
           Next
           dAccumulator = dAccumulator * CLng(10 ^ 9)
           PHash = CLng(dAccumulator)
End Function
```

Comment: do you need to match values generated by the old code?  if not, just do pValue.GetHashCode() which is a method that exists on every object in C#/.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really hope you have a reference or two to test with, but this is the best I could come up with

```
    private static long PHash(String pValue)
    {
        double dAccumulator = 0;
        byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pValue.Trim().ToUpper());
        for (int i = 0; i < asciiBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((i & 1) == 1)
                dAccumulator = Math.Cos(dAccumulator + (double)asciiBytes[i]);
            else
                dAccumulator = Math.Sin(dAccumulator + (double)asciiBytes[i]);
        }
        dAccumulator = dAccumulator * Math.Pow(10,9);
        return (long)dAccumulator;
    }
```

There was no reason to do a direct translation, because it involved a lot of waste. I replaced all the string parsing logic with a conversion to a byte array, which was then iterated through with a for loop. We used the `&` operator to replicate the AND operator in VB. `Sin` and `Cos` are now methods of the `Math` class, the string can be trimmed and converted to uppercase by chaining the methods `Trim()` and `ToUpper()`. There is no exponential operator in .NET, so `Math.Pow()` is the replacement for it. Note we keep everything as doubles right up until the return line, where we return the value as a `long`

Comment: Wouldn't `i == 1` be equivalent to `(i & 1) == 1`?

Comment: I do have references. For example the string test gets hashed in the original to -999740276

The code above does not work.. I suspect it is something to do with the original reason that 
If (lTemp AND 1) = 1 Then
was used..

Comment: Oh Doh.. Just figured it out. The original test 
(i And 1) = 1
Is using the Sin function on odd numbers (based on 1 based array) hence the bitwise operation.
All I needed to do to the code from @Lathejockey was to add 1 to a variable and test that variable:
lTemp = i + 1;
 if ((lTemp & 1) == 1)

Comment: Oh, forgot to flip them based on the zero index. Good call. I will update the code.

Comment: Technically, it's `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)` not `Encoding.Ascii` for the equivalent of Asc. Though it may not matter for most values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. See converstion tool :http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/?batchId=dbded81a-54c9-4df5-aced-4db45773c842

```
  public object PHash(pValue)
  {
   dynamic dValue = null;
   dynamic dAccumulator = null;
   dynamic lTemp = null;
   dynamic sValue = null;
   sValue = Strings.UCase(Strings.Trim("" + pValue));
   dAccumulator = 0;
   for (lTemp = 1; lTemp <= Strings.Len(sValue); lTemp++) {
    dValue = Strings.Asc(Strings.Mid(sValue, lTemp, 1));
    if ((lTemp & 1) == 1) {
        dAccumulator = Sin(dAccumulator + dValue);
    } else {
        dAccumulator = Cos(dAccumulator + dValue);
    }
}
 dAccumulator = dAccumulator * Convert.ToInt64(Math.Pow(10, 9));
 return Convert.ToInt64(dAccumulator);
 }
```

Comment: This is the problem with code converters. You need to go over the result and tweak it. This one did not catch the zero index requirement to parse strings. It is much better to move to more .NET friendly methods instead.

Answer (score -1):

The translation could be something like this:

```
public long PHash (string pValue)
{
    int dValue;
    double dAccumulator;
    int lTemp;
    string sValue;

    sValue = pValue.Trim().ToUpper();
    dAccumulator = 0;

    for (lTemp = 1; lTemp <= sValue.Length; lTemp ++)
    {
        dValue = (int)char.Parse(sValue.Substring(lTemp, 1));
        if ((lTemp % 1) == 1)
        {
            dAccumulator = Math.Sin(dAccumulator  + dValue);
        }
        else
        {
            dAccumulator = Math.Cos(dAccumulator  + dValue);
        }
    }
    dAccumulator = dAccumulator * (long)(10 ^ 9);
    return (long)(dAccumulator);
}
```

The function translated were:
Trim: Removes spaces on both the left and the right side of a string. In C#: Trim().
UCase: Converts a specified string to uppercase. In C#: ToUpper().
Mid: Returns a specified number of characters from a string. In C#: Substring().
Len: Returns the number of characters in a string. In C#: Length.
CLng: Is a simple cast to the long type.
Asc: Is resolved as a simply cast to an int from a char.

Comment: `10 ^ 9` is a bitwise operation in C#, not an exponential operator. `%` is a remainder operator, so it is not a suitable replacement for AND. Strings in .NET are always indexed by zero, so this method would likely throw an exception.