# Generate hash using PHASH with PHP

Tags: php, asp-classic, phash

How can I generate a `PHASH` value from a string in `PHP`?

I've inherited an `ASP` codebase that utilizes `PHASH` with `strings` (*not paths to images*). From research, `PHASH` is used for images.

I'm currently rewriting this part of the codebase using `PHP`, and there's a couple of libraries that seem useful:

- https://github.com/jenssegers/imagehash
- https://github.com/xwiz/phash/blob/master/phash.php

*However*, they both require a path to an image. I've tried `jenssegers/imagehash` and this throws an exception when I pass a random string.

Code below of how `PHASH` is currently used within the legacy codebase:

```
sLoginPassword = RequestValue("Password")
SQLVal(PHASH(sLoginPassword))
```

## Update

`PHASH` is a custom function within the codebase, I failed to find it originally due to mixed casing (`PHash` vs `PHASH`).

Luckily I found the following [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582667/legacy-vbscript-to-c-sharp-equivilent) which is written in `C#`. Thanks to @Lathejockey81 for provding the answer, I've converted this into PHP below (as an answer).

Comment: Fortunately I've found this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582667/legacy-vbscript-to-c-sharp-equivilent - AND, after digging deeper it looks like this is a custom function, although the function is referenced as `PHash`, not `PHASH`

Comment: You want to hash a password? why not use built in hashes like `sha1()`

Comment: Nope, I want to know how to reverse engineer the `PHash` function linked above in PHP :) - I'll provide an answer shortly once I've converted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom `PHASH` function converted from [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582667/legacy-vbscript-to-c-sharp-equivilent):

```
function PHASH($string)
{
    $value = trim(strtoupper($string));

    $dAccumulator = 0;
    $asciiBytes = [];

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); $i++) {
        $asciiBytes[] = ord($value[$i]);
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < count($asciiBytes); $i++) {
        if(($i & 1) == 1) {
            $dAccumulator = cos($dAccumulator + (float) $asciiBytes[$i]);
        } else {
            $dAccumulator = sin($dAccumulator + (float) $asciiBytes[$i]);
        }
    }
    $dAccumulator = $dAccumulator * pow(10, 9);

    return round($dAccumulator);
}
```